# Why do my cols flex-grow in Bootstrap 4 are not aligned?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

With Bootstrap 4, I want my cols to be align in multiple row.

If I set rows and cols it works just fine but if one of my col need to fit 2 slot with `flex-grow:2` it create a little gap between rows. I tried every flex's stuff with no success.

Here you can have the link to try it. I created 2 cases, one with divs and the other (the one I care) with a table with the row class.

[Link on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8HYTXDQ4CCH)

```css
  .col{  
     border:1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="flex-grow:2.08">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">        
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col">Firstname</th>
        <th class="col">Lastname</th>
        <th class="col">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col" style="flex-grow:2">John (2.07 in flex-grow works in 1080p...)</td>
        <td class="d-none">Doe</td>
        <td class="col">john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col">Mary</td>
        <td class="col">Moe</td>
        <td class="col">mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col">July</td>
        <td class="col">Dooley</td>
        <td class="col">july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
In the first example you can see a little gap between the "1" / "2" and "2" / "3" and its the same in the second example.

I really need to use flex-grow because in my full code some of my TDs have a fixed width in PX and others TDs need to fit empty space but with the same width (or twice if I set the flex-grow:2)

Comment: Please post your code to the question, not an offsite link. If that link every disappears, this question will be useless to future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that W3 schools has noticed an issue too, hence their "2.07 in flex-grow...".

I'm not sure why it's occurring, but a work-around can be to add a class to those td's and then add media queries for that class at different screen sizes.

For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) { 
    .alter-flex{
        flex-grow: 2.09;
    }
}
```